# thread instance new and old java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, instance

I was learning about the java threads ( synchronization and locks ) but somehow i was not able to find the difference between these two things.

```
// Two different instances of SyncExample
Thread a1 = new Thread(new SyncExample(), "A");
Thread b1 = new Thread(new SyncExample(), "B");

// Same instance is passed to both the threads
SyncExample syn = new SyncExample();
Thread a2 = new Thread(syn, "A");
Thread b2 = new Thread(syn, "B");

// I believe in total 4 stacks are built.
a1.start();
b1.start();

a2.start();
b2.start();

public class SyncExample implements Runnable {

    Object obj = new Object();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        this.myName();
    }

    private void myName() {

        synchronized (obj) {
            System.out.print("Define" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            System.out.print("tly" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
        System.out.println(" Maybe" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}


public class SyncExample implements Runnable {

    Object obj = new Object();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        this.myName();
    }

    private void myName() {

        synchronized (obj) {
            System.out.print("Define" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            System.out.print("tly" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
        System.out.println(" Maybe" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

But the problem here is when i run this example using the

1 - Same reference output is :

```
DefineAtlyA MaybeA
DefineBtlyB MaybeB
```

2 - 2 different instances :

```
DefineADefineBtlyAtlyB MaybeB
 MaybeA
```

Can ayone explain me what difference it makes when we pass the runnable target to Thread class
1. Same instance
2. Different instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code, when you pass two different instances (of `SyncExample` class), each instance has its own lock object (held by variable `obj`). As there are two different lock objects, each thread acquires a lock and executes in parallel, resulting in interleaved output of thread A and B (`DefineADefineBtlyAtlyB MaybeB MaybeA`).

Whereas when you pass the same instance, there is just one instance of `SyncExample` class. As a result, there is just one instance of the lock object (held by variable `obj`). Hence this lock object will be shared between the two threads. Due to this sharing, only one thread (say T1) will be able to enter the synchronized block; the other thread (say T2) would wait till T1 exists the synchronized block. Therefore in your execution, you see all print statements for thread A first, followed by all statements for thread B (`DefineAtlyA MaybeA DefineBtlyB MaybeB`).

If I were to generalized this: when you pass different instances, only static variables would affect the parallel execution of the threads, but when you pass a single instance, both the static and class level variables (such as the `obj` variable in your code) will affect the parallel execution of the threads.

Comment: Wow. That explains everything. I was confused, was thinking that obj acquires the Thread A's lock, infact it was exact opposite. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The output should hint you on the difference.

When you pass in the same `SyncExample` to two different threads, only one of them will be able to acquire lock on `obj` and execute the code in `synchronized` block.

When you pass in two different `SyncExample` objects, both of the threads are able to execute simultaneously because they are synchronizing on different objects.

Comment: Yes i can get that from the output, but my question is why and how ??

Comment: What do you mean saying "why"? Have you read anything about synchronization and `synchronized` keyword?

Comment: Well i believe Kshitij's comment made everyhting clear to me. Yes i was not clear about the concepts that's why question was asked. Thanks  for the help Andrew Logvinov. :-)